# Postgresql query containing a constant in a logical-or leads to full table scan

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, boolean-logic

I have a query that contains a clause of the form `CONSTANT OR t.foo=:foo`, where CONSTANT is some expression that evaluates to a constant boolean value. Then the query is executed as a full table scan, even when there is an index on column foo and the simple `t.foo=:foo` would use the index. The example query that I analyzed had the form `:foo IS NOT NULL OR t.foo=:foo`. Here is a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE tst (
id serial,
name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
age INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID));

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tst WHERE (23 IS NOT NULL OR id=23);
                       QUERY PLAN                       
--------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on tst  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40)
```

Is there any reason for this? Is there a way to tell the optimizer to logically evaluate/simplify the query?

Comment: `where (23 IS NOT NULL OR id=23)` is the same as `where (true or id = 23)` which is the same as `where true` which is the same as not having a `where` condition at all. So you request all  rows of the table, and the most efficient way to do that is a Seq Scan

Comment: You are right, this was totally non-sense. I tried to simplify a more complex example, but this is of cause a full-table scan because the WHERE-part is true.